# Svelte store trigger from other page

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

In Sveltekit, I need to find a way to trigger a state change by making a request to a different page.

Say:

Index.svelte

```
<script>
import { count } from '../stores.js';
</script>

{$count}
```

stores.js

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

export const count = writable(0);
```

Now when I visit, for example, localhost:3000/api, I want the count to ++ & reflect on the index.svelte file.

I tried

api.svelte

```
<script>
    import { count } from '../stores.js';
    count.update(n => n + 1);
</script>
```

But this does not work at all. Code does work when I place it in a function in index.svelte and trigger it with a button for example. Any directions?

Answer (score 0):

Try using onMount:

```
import { onMount } from 'svelte';

onMount(async () => {
    count.update((n) => n + 1);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is also not working. No updates are taking place to the counter!